# Frame animation moves across screen multiple times

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I have a frame animation (two ImageViews in a loop) and I move that across the screen with animate().translationXBy(x); I want the app to keep moving the animation across as long as the app is on. Regular loops like for() do not work for some reason a newbie like me doesn't understand. Here is some code:

```
private ImageView thing;
private AnimationDrawable movingthing;
private int width;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    thing= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.pics);
    thing.setImageResource(R.drawable.thingthatmoves);
    movingthing = (AnimationDrawable)thing.getDrawable();
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

// happens twice
public void send(){
    moveThatThing();
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        moveThatThing();
        }
    }, 3000);
}

public void moveThatThing(){
    thing.setX(-10);
    x = width;
    movingthing.start();
    thing.animate().setDuration(3000);
    thing.animate().translationXBy(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a runnable.

Add a handler to your oncreate method:

```
Handler h=new Handler();
h.postDelayed(move, 0);
```

And then add in this runnable to your class

```
Runnable move = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
            moveThatThing();
            h.postDelayed(move, 3000);
        }
};
```

I tested in a basic application and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you are looking for is a while loop.

So the format of your application should be something like

```
while(programIsStillRunning){
    updateYourAnimation();
}
```

or maybe

```
while(theUserHasNotExitedTheProgram){
    updateYourAnimation();
}
```

You could just put it in a while loop that will run forever, but that is not usually the best way to do it.

Comment: I have tried while loop too and it loops wonderfully only it doesn't show anything